# How do I write a variable in javascript from getelementbyid

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

This is probably a simple question ( or I assume to be ) however, I still can't get it to work no matter how much i twinker with it. I am trying to write a variable inside a li tag. This variable should hold the text within another div tag like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var item = document.getElementById('thistext').innerHTML;
                    function songlist () {
document.write("<div class='overview'><ul><li> item </li></ul></div>");
}
</script>


<div id="thistext">hello</div>

<!-- I want it to appear here -->
<div class="viewport">
<script type="text/javascript">
songlist ();
</script>
</div>
```

So basically I need the text within "thistext" div tag to appear within the li tag which is within the ul etc (I don't know if thats unnecessary info or not ) I've also tried putting the script and its function within the viewport tag itself and with:

```
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "value";
```

that layout too but it doesn't appear to be showing working and I can't seem to understand why. I'm looking forward to the responses and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change it to

```
document.write("<div class='overview'><ul><li>" + item + "</li></ul></div>");
```

Comment: And don't try to read the element before its been loaded in the document.

Comment: Ah thanks that works, However it seems to come up with "undefined" is that because the "this text" is still loading after the viewport has loaded?

Comment: Put the first script below the div. (i.e. make it the last thing on the page)

Comment: or is the $(document).ready() a possibility? as I have recently read up about it.

Comment: Yes, but you'll have to change around your script to work. You'd end up putting  `songlist ();` into the `$(document).ready()` function. You'd then have to change your songlist function to be `$('.viewport').innerHTML("<div class='overview'><ul><li>" + item + "</li></ul></div>")`

Comment: @NeilKennedy `.append()` would be what he needs there, not `.innerHtml()`

Answer (score 3):

```
document.write("<div class='overview'><ul><li> item </li></ul></div>");
```

needs to be

```
document.write('<div class="overview"><ul><li>' + item + ' </li></ul></div>');
```

Edit:

I feel like I should point out that this isn't the best way to achieve this. Maybe something like this would better...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload = function(){
      document.getElementById('viewport').innerHtml = document.getElementById('thistext').innerHtml;
   };
</script>
```

Saying that, have you looked in the [jQuery](http://jquery.com) framework at all? It makes DOM manipulation very easy. There is a time and a place for it though. If all you're doing is replacing the text in one `<div>` with the text from another `<div>` then maybe its not appropriate.

Comment: Hmm I will look into that because I was thinking of implementing this idea throughout my site. thanks. But, viewport is a class and not a id would the "getelementbyid" still work for that?

Comment: oops sorry, missed that. `getElementById` would not work on a class. Using jQuery however you could use `$('.viewport')` instead. You can use almost anything to get a DOM element in jQuery :)

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
document.write("<div class='overview'><ul><li>" + item + "</li></ul></div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

-now it works:
You are missing '' in getElementById and teh function has to be moved after the div
and you have to place the variable with surrounded by +''+  in the document write

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fMNWt/

```
<div id="thistext">hello</div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
var item = document.getElementById('thistext').innerHTML;
                    function songlist () {
document.write("<div class='overview'><ul><li>" + item + "</li></ul></div>");
}
</script>  
<!-- I want it to appear here -->
<div class="viewport">
<script type="text/javascript">
songlist ();
</script>
</div>
```